# Toolbar blind fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

My project I use toolbar 
But Toolbar blind fragment

how to solve this problem
sry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detailsry this code detail

And [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri9sL.jpg)Can you exclude margins?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4wic.jpg)

this code how can i change this??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

    <Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_bar_start">
    </Toolbar>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_viewer_start"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        tools:context=".fragment.StartFragment" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mainStartRunning"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="RUNNING"
            style="@style/buttonTextRedText"
            android:background="@drawable/button_empty_background"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mainStartRacing"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="RACING"
            style="@style/buttonText"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add your code with xml?

Comment: Yes i edited my code

Comment: not available Relativelayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Either** use `layout_below` attribute of `RelativeLayout` like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ...>
    </Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_layout"
        ...>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ...>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Or** Use `LinearLayout` with `orientation` vertical

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Toolbar
        ...>
    </Toolbar>


    <LinearLayout
        ...>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: my MainActivity is error ... button missing i edit my code

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: how can i aceppt?!!

Comment: okay !! thank you

I am new to using stackoverflow. Please understand.